# Pandas Datetime: Aggregate based on time lag

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, aggregate

I have a data frame with 3 columns, containing id, timestamp and event type:

```
    id      timestamp   event_type
    ___________________________
0   1       2019-10-01      E1
1   1       2019-10-03      E3
2   2       2019-10-04      E3
3   2       2019-10-05      E4
4   2       2019-10-06      E1
5   1       2019-10-07      E3
6   1       2019-10-07      E4
7   1       2019-10-13      E3
8   2       2019-10-22      E5
```

And I am looking for a way to aggregate it, so that rows belonging to the same id and having a time lag < X days are aggregated together. Lets say `X=3` for the examples sake.

I.e. row 0 and row 1 should result to one list, as their timestamps are not more than 3 days apart.

So my desired output is the following:

```
    id2     event_hist
    _______________
0   1-1     [E1, E3]
1   2-1     [E3, E4, E1]
2   1-2     [E3, E4]
3   1-3     [E3]
4   2-2     [E5]
```

the id2 column is just the id from the first data frame, iterated up for each new sequence.

I could write a function to achieve the desired result, but is there a built-in method?
whats the most pythonic way the get the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if column timestamp is not datetime, start with that

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

t = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda g: g.rolling('3d', on='timestamp').count())
new = df.groupby(t['id'].le(t.shift()['id']).cumsum()) \
        .agg(event_hist=('event_type', list), id2=('id', 'first'))
new['id2'] = new['id2'].astype(str) + \
                '-' + \
                new.groupby('id2').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```

results in

```
            hist  id2
id                   
0       [E1, E3]  1-1
1   [E3, E4, E1]  2-1
2       [E3, E4]  1-2
3           [E3]  1-3
4           [E5]  2-2
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my question, which seems to work. Though I think the answer @splash58 proposed is more efficient and uses less lines and more built-in functions.

```
def get_aggregate_by_lag(df, idcol, datecol, valuecol, max_lag):
    import pandas as pd

    res_dict = {}
    for id in df[idcol].unique():
        sub_df = df[df[idcol] == id].reset_index(drop=True)

        current_sequence = [sub_df[valuecol][0]]

        sequence_counter = 1

        if len(sub_df) == 1:
            res_dict[f"{id}-{sequence_counter}"] = [current_sequence]
            continue

        for i in range(1,len(sub_df)):
            if (sub_df[datecol][i] - sub_df[datecol][i-1]).days <= max_lag:
                current_sequence.append(sub_df[valuecol][i])
                if i == len(sub_df)-1:
                    res_dict[f"{id}-{sequence_counter}"] = [current_sequence]
            else:
                res_dict[f"{id}-{sequence_counter}"] = [current_sequence]
                sequence_counter += 1
                current_sequence = [sub_df[valuecol][i]]

    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(res_dict, columns=["hist"], orient="Index")
```